# YouTube Regex: Tested to pick up both video and playlist ID, yet Node.js won't

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, hyperlink, youtube

I have the following regex, which has been tested across three different sites to match all YouTube links and also capture both video ID and also an optional playlist ID. Despite this, my Node app doesn't pick up anything but the video ID:

```
/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((?:\w|-|_){11})(?:(?:\?|\&)index=((?:\d){1,3}))?(?:(?:\?|\&)list=((?:\w|-|_){24}))?(?:\S+)?/g
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/MpKLrkWUCEiXRJyG)

My actual code:

```
var youtube = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((?:\w|-|_){11})(?:(?:\?|\&)index=((?:\d){1,3}))?(?:(?:\?|\&)list=((?:\w|-|_){24}))?(?:\S+)?/g;
ansCopy = ansCopy.replace(youtube, "^~$1~^~$3~^");
```

Using "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWKdcalZTaA&list=UUlucBMqhrYW4PWuIp8Um_cg&index=46" as a test string, this should produce the string:

```
"^~VWKdcalZTaA~^~UUlucBMqhrYW4PWuIp8Um_cg~^"
```

But it instead produces:

```
"^~VWKdcalZTaA~^~~^"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the regex wasn't picking up the playlist ID properly due to some sanitation code which would replace the first "&" with it's HTML notation counterpart, interfering with the regex and only returning a match with the video ID. My regex now accepts both "&" and "& #38;" where necessary:

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+(?:&|&#38;);v=))((?:\w|-|_){11})(?:(?:\?|&|&#38;)index=((?:\d){1,3}))?(?:(?:\?|&|&#38;)list=((?:\w|-|_){24}))?(?:\S+)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ycoahAdJECdOcVMQ)

Answer (score 3):

It's a URL, so why not use Node.js URL module.

```
var url = require('url');
var youtube = url.parse('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWKdcalZTaA&list=UUlucBMqhrYW4PWuIp8Um_cg&index=46');
/*{
    protocol: 'http:',
    slashes: true,
    auth: null,
    host: 'www.youtube.com',
    port: null,
    hostname: 'www.youtube.com',
    hash: null,
    search: '?v=VWKdcalZTaA&list=UUlucBMqhrYW4PWuIp8Um_cg&index=46',
    query: 'v=VWKdcalZTaA&list=UUlucBMqhrYW4PWuIp8Um_cg&index=46',
    pathname: '/watch',
    path: '/watch?v=VWKdcalZTaA&list=UUlucBMqhrYW4PWuIp8Um_cg&index=46',
    href: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWKdcalZTaA&list=UUlucBMqhrYW4PWuIp8Um_cg&index=46'
}*/
var query = querystring.parse(youtube.query); 
/*{
    v: 'VWKdcalZTaA',
    list: 'UUlucBMqhrYW4PWuIp8Um_cg',
    index: '46'
}*/
```

Comment: Is it really that easy...? Where are you getting querystring from?

Comment: Querystring is provided by Node.js as well, http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

Comment: So I found out why the regex wasn't picking up correctly. My code is parsing down all of the &'s in the URL.

Comment: I try to avoid RegEx if I can.

Comment: I get why, but a friend of mine keeps pushing regexes insanely hard, and I happened to find the "ultimate" YouTube link regex, which I then improved. Long story short, some sanitization code kept interfering with the link. I added optional detection of the HTML notation of "&", so it works now.